# Youtube api question, make a perfect copy of a playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Im not experienced with webdev so i want to know if this is possible before figuring out how to do it.

I want to know if im able to create to duplicate a playlist  and keep all the data pertaining to the added videos (including deleted videos added to that playlist and the original dates each video was added). In other words, make a carbon copy by any method possible.

Im not sure if youtubes api can do this since as far as a i know what it can currently do is make a new playlist and add all the videos again, which is not the solution im searching for.

Ive tried creating a new playlist and bringing the videos using youtube music but that does not bring deleted vieos or the original add dates.

Comment: You assume not being the owner of this playlist or/and its videos, right?

Comment: I am the owner of the playlist but not the videos, its a music playlist with songs ive liked over the years and i want to make an exact copy of it because it recently got full (5000 videos) and i want to make multiple of its kind but condensated by the year i added the song while still keeping dleted videos and the original add date.

Comment: Without having investigated more the following point, what you are looking for seems technically doable but possibly is overkill like it requires to make an offline copy of all the videos of the playlist etc. The point I mentioned earlier is that I doubt that you can fake *the original dates each video was added*, should make sure by investigating with [a low-level approach manipulating the Protobuf sent to the YouTube UI](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/256).

Comment: I see, so it could be done but i would need to look more into that Protbuf thing to be sure. Could it also retain all the deleted videos added that are no longe available on youtube to the playlist (the playlist shows them as deleted/privated video and i cant add them to any playlis) im interested mostly on those since i want to look later more on them to find a replacement. Sigh, in any way, could a complete begginer with coding achieve to do this or would i need to get help from someone? Ive never worked with an api before

Comment: Concerning deleted/private videos, you cannot retrieve their actual video content once they are defined as deleted/private. To ensure still having access to them once they are defined as such, you should beforehands download them locally.

Comment: i do not want to have the video itself, but i would like to keep the slot that they take and their asociated link (even if the video is deleted/privated they keep their link) on the duplicate playlist, its just to remind that there was a video there before, could that be done?

Comment: I just verified and you cannot add a deleted/private video to a playlist. Note that even `Add all to...` on https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLAYLIST_ID does not help to do so.

Comment: oh then i guess that says it, guess what im asking wont work since i want to keep the playlist with deleted videos and their original add date, guess the only way to have a deleted video on your playlist is to have had that video when it was active on the first place. Well, thanks for informing me anyways , i couldnt thank you enough :)